# Partial Class with CollectionDataContract Attribute not partial after reference update

Tags: wcf, silverlight, class, partial

I've a Silverlight application with wcf service. I defined a partial class server side like this

```
[CollectionDataContract(Namespace = "http://test/datacontract")]
 public partial class ItemTypeObjectList : List<ItemTypeObject>, IWcfObject
 {
 }
```

If I execute the "Update Service Reference" on the Service Reference (clientside), the "partial" modifier is not existing in Reference.cs. In Refernce.cs it looks like this:

```
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
 [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Runtime.Serialization", "4.0.0.0")]
 [System.Runtime.Serialization.CollectionDataContractAttribute(Name="ItemTypeObjectList", Namespace="http://test/datacontract", ItemName="ItemTypeObject")]
 public class ItemTypeObjectList : System.Collections.Generic.List<Test.DataContract.ItemTypeObject> {
 }
```

The "partial" is missing -> Why?

Thank you very much for a solution.

Best regards.
 Ivan